# WHERE datatable.column = '' is not working on live SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable

I know there are many answers to the question of how do I check a column / row cell is empty or NULL out there and although they seem to give the correct way to do this I can only get it to work on my local server, not my live server, so wondering if anyone out there can help please.

Problem:

edit: The *.cancelled = ''* part of the code snippet works fine on my local pc but will not work on the live server. Note, The *dateFrom* works fine without the *AND .... .cancelled = ''* part.

```
WHERE (ReservationDetailsTable.dateFrom = '" + chosenDatefrom + "') AND (ReservationDetailsTable.cancelled = '')
```

also tried using

```
ReservationDetailsTable.cancelled IS NULL
```

and

```
ReservationDetailsTable.cancelled LIKE ''
```

and

```
DATALENGTH(ReservationDetailsTable.cancelled) = 0
```

none work on the server version. All I want is as long as the cancelled column has no data in it then it is selected.

I have checked what is in the column / row cell and that all other data matches the SQL statement, I've checked spelling of column name, etc. It works and filters by data in the cell if I put a string inside the ' and ' but not if I don't.

Is its possible that even though I can put data in to the datatable then delete it it is not null or actually empty?

I'm not an SQL server expert I can just write SQL command statements.

cheers for any help.

EDITTED as can't add a comment..

Cancelled data = Both are data format NVARCHAR(23). It is to store a string. Tried both date formats 03/12/14 and 12/03/14 already. thanks all so far.

Comment: If it works on one instance of sql server and doesnt work on another instance, you probably need to look into your `data` not the query.

Comment: What is the data type of `ReservationDetailsTable.cancelled`? How are you calling the query?

Comment: If I had to guess, the problem is in the other part of the condition.  If you remove the `cancelled` condition is anything returned?  My suspicion is that the default date formats are different on the two servers and this prevents a match on the first condition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand a little thing, I suppose `cancelled` field has a data type as DATE or DATETIME, so why do you want put your condition with ''?

But, if for you that condition is ok, have you tried this?

```
WHERE (ReservationDetailsTable.dateFrom = '" + chosenDatefrom + "')
AND (ReservationDetailsTable.cancelled is null OR ReservationDetailsTable.cancelled = '')
```